# How can I make this variable size table output images from a GLOB Array?

Tags: php, html, html-table, glob

I have to make a table with an amount of columns that can be set by a variable ($cols) with each cell containing a picture obtained through a GLOB Array. The code I have now will output a table with the correct amount of cells and columns but I need help getting each picture to show up.

```
<?php
$cols = 4;

$array = glob("include/*.{jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);


$output = "<table>\n";

$cell_count = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($cell_count == 1) {
        $output .= "<tr>\n";
    }
    $output .= "<td><img src=$array></td>\n";
    $cell_count++;

    if ($cell_count > $cols || $i == (count($array) - 1)) {
        $output .= "</tr>\n";
        $cell_count = 1;
    }
}
$output .= "</table>\n";
echo "$output";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not indexing into the array to get a single item. This:

```
$output .= "<td><img src=$array></td>\n";
```

should be

```
$output .= "<td><img src=\"$array[$i]\"></td>\n";
```

Note also that I am escaping the double quotes so that your HTML src attribute value is double quoted.

Also, you could make the **for** statement more efficient if you cache **count($array)** in another variable, although it might not be a big deal.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!